# Button breaking the bottom border

Tags: html, button, html-table

Hello for some reason I have a button that is breaking the bottom border that I have already set in place for my table. I eventually want to do this for all of my rows, but I would like to know how to prevent that from happening. Each row in my table should have a button, but I'd like to keep my borders intact.

```css
table{

  color: #26004d;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 30px;

}

th, td{
  padding: 30px 50px 30px 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #862d59;
}

th{
 color: black;
}


tr:hover{

 background-color: lightgreen;
}


.button{

  background-color: #26004d;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border:none;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
 <div id="inner">


 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Pet</th>
    <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Cat</td>
    <td>$10</td>
    <td><button class="button">Buy Now</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Lion</td>
    <td>$40</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Flamingo</td>
    <td>$50</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Panda</td>
    <td>$1000</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>


 </div>
```

Comment: Wow I just realized that wasn't the case. It's merely the fact that the rows are expanding. Sorry, little bit of an "off" title. But how would one go about adjusting the width of a smaller row to fit the widths of the bigger rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you must put `button` into `td`, because it's in table, but you're applying the `border-bottom` property to `td` so you have border under `button`, if you want to remove it you can add a class `no-border` and apply it to `td` in which you have your `button` so look at code, and you'll have only two  columns have border, or another solution is to add `<td></td>` or `<th></th>` where appropriate into every `<tr>`that has no `button`.

```css
table{

  color: #26004d;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 30px;

}

th, td{
  padding: 30px 50px 30px 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #862d59;
}
.no-border{
  border:none;
}
th{
 color: black;
}


tr:hover{

 background-color: lightgreen;
}


.button{

  background-color: #26004d;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border:none;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
 <div id="inner">


 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Pet</th>
    <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Cat</td>
    <td>$10</td>
    <td class="no-border"><button class="button">Buy Now</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Lion</td>
    <td>$40</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Flamingo</td>
    <td>$50</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Panda</td>
    <td>$1000</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>


 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** Uneven number of column inside each row.

**Solution:** Either enter blank `<td></td>` or use [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp).

```css
table{

  color: #26004d;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 30px;

}

th, td{
  padding: 30px 50px 30px 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #862d59;
}

th{
 color: black;
}


tr:hover{

 background-color: lightgreen;
}


.button{

  background-color: #26004d;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border:none;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner">


 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Pet</th>
    <th>Price</th>
                <th></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Cat</td>
    <td>$10</td>
    <td><button class="button">Buy Now</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Lion</td>
    <td colspan="2">$40</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Flamingo</td>
    <td>$50</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Panda</td>
    <td>$1000</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>


 </div>
```